# Microsoft OPOS hangs on Claim after PC restart

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, opos, posiflex

I am using ***'Microsoft Point of Service for .NET v1.14.'*** dlls to connect with Posiflex Thermal Printer (PP8800 model).
Code snippet which I am using is also pasted below. I am running this code from WPF application.

But I am facing one strange issue. If printer is powered on and machine on which the printer is connected is restarted, below pasted code is not able to claim the printer and it also does not come out of the `Claim()` statement. Whereas if I power off the printer and then power it on before running the below code snippet then it is able to claim the printer.

```
PosExplorer posExplorer = new PosExplorer();
var printerList = posExplorer.GetDevices(DeviceType.PosPrinter);

foreach (DeviceInfo item in printerList)
{
    if (item.ServiceObjectName != printerName)
        continue;

    posPrinter = (PosPrinter)posExplorer.CreateInstance(item);
    posPrinter.Open();

    posPrinter.PowerNotify = PowerNotification.Enabled;
    posPrinter.FlagWhenIdle = true;
    posPrinter.StatusUpdateEvent += PosPrinter_StatusUpdateEvent;
    posPrinter.DirectIOEvent += PosPrinter_DirectIOEvent;
    posPrinter.ErrorEvent += PosPrinter_ErrorEvent;
    posPrinter.OutputCompleteEvent += PosPrinter_OutputCompleteEvent;

    try
    {
        posPrinter.Claim(100);
        if (posPrinter.Claimed)
        {
            isPrinterClaimed = true;                           
        }
        else
        {    
            isPrinterClaimed = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        isPrinterClaimed = false;
    }

    break;
}
```

Has anybody faced the same issue while using OPOS libraries?

Comment: Perhaps you are using a LAN interface printer and are you shutting down your POS without calling the Release/Close method? Such a phenomenon may occur depending on the control/implementation method of the printer and the POSfor.NET/OPOS service object. Printer vendors may have a collection of such cases, so please contact vender for issues and how to deal with them.

Comment: Thank you @kunif for youe comment. I have connected printer on USB port and yes, I am releasing the printer before application closes. I am also in contact with Vendor, but not received a reply yet.